# Selenium Webdrive (Java) - find an element where attribute is disabled=""

Tags: java, selenium

I have `<input id="test" disabled="">`. How can I find this element with an attribute disabled="".

P.S I don't need to use id in this case. I want to find an element with the disabled attribute.

I've tried to use

```
String enbl = Login.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#test")).getAttribute("disabled=''");
```

But I've got the null result

Comment: Have you looked at the [`isEnabled`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled%28%29) method on a `WebElement`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this method, but it's not working. In my case it's return false

Comment: Isn't that what you want? `isEnabled` to return `false` if the element is `disabled`? Or are you saying that it returns `false` for an `enabled` element?

Comment: For performance, you should not find the element explicitly by using XPath with a "disabled" check inside it. Find it another way and use it's `isEnabled` property. Clarify whether this is true/false for your element and what you are expecting it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `xpath`

```
//input[@id='test'][@disabled='']
```

With `css`

```
[id='test'][disabled='']
```

*Note: There is a chance that you need to add additional wait before searching for the element*

Answer (score 3):

One idea would be using an XPath. Something like this:

```
By.xpath("//input[@id = 'test'][@disabled = '']")
```

You can probably do it with CSS selectors too, though I don't know the syntax there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the xpath like this:

`//input[@id='text' and @disabled='']`

Or, if you just want to test, **if the element is enabled or not**, as @mystarrocks suspects, you can use the below code:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element"));
if(ele.isEnabled())
  System.out.println("Element is enabled");
else
  System.out.println("Element is disabled");
```